# How to create a batch file for accessing multiple python file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have multiple python file. To get acces on that file i've created a main.py. Main.py is using a GUI (from Tkinter) to get access on the other python file.

Know I'm trying to create a batch file were I can open my project without using Visualstudio. I have done something and if I run this File, the main.py will open. But if i click on the Button which i created in my main.py, I'm getting a error message like this:

> python: can't open file 'opendata.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

```
@echo off
python C:\Users\KL\pro\project34\main.py  %*
start
pause
```

How can I implement it so that I can access the other data?

Comment: What is the location of `opendata.py` in relation to `main.py`?

Comment: Its the same location. All python files which the main.py need is saved in `C:\Users\KL\pro\project34`. So the pathon from `opendata.py` is `C:\Users\KL\pro\project34\opendata.py`

Comment: and the `batch-file` location?

Comment: This lies in the desktop. Do you mean that i have to save it into the same path as the project file is?

Comment: Well, I cannot say for sure because I cannot see your python code, but I would assume you have told the python code that the location of the files should be in its current directory? I would however do: this instead `cd /d "C:\Users\KL\pro\project34\" && python main.py %*`

Comment: Thx for your information. I moved it to my project folder and it works.

Comment: change your batch file then to do what I showed you in the last comment, you should then be able to leave it on the desktop for easy access.